# Why does hitting the left arrow in irb give me "^[[D"?

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm using Ubuntu Server 10 lucid, ruby 1.9.2-p0. In irb, the left arrow shows `^[[D`. Any idea?

Comment: ...as opposed to what? At the very least you'll need a readline-aware irb I believe.

Comment: As for "why": Because that's what the raw command sequence looks like rendered as characters when the console does not specifically handle this key (for example by moving the cursor to the left). :)

Comment: @deceze thanks for explain the details for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

and then reinstall ruby and irb.

Comment: Kind of a longshot, but do you have any sources on what causes this?  
On Ubuntu I had to install this package and recompile ruby to get up arrow to work.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, if you are using RVM, just remember to install readline:

```
rvm pkg install readline
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Over the apt package, this has the advantage of giving you the 1.9.3 version, which IMHO is more stable.

Comment: In my case, I just needed to `rvm reinstall <ruby version>`.  No other action needed regarding packages or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

IRB is installed with Ruby. I had this problem where it worked and then stopped working. I updated Ruby (rvm install ruby-) and it works again.